# Installing gems on jruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jruby

I've worked with ruby, and ROR but this new project is requiring me to use jruby.  And I have been given documentation ad it is asking me to install jgem install cucumber, ect..

I am doing this on Ubuntu 10.10

I don't understand the jgem part.

I Did some research and tried to install it via:
`jruby -S gem install cucumber`

and got the output:

```
JRuby limited openssl loaded. gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
http://jruby.kenai.com/pages/JRuby_Builtin_OpenSSL
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (SystemCallError)
    Unknown error - mkdir failed
```

And I tried to install: `gem install jruby-openssl`
and got the same results

Comment: Looks like some permission problem for the path where gems will be installed. Can you check if GEM_HOME env variable has proper permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds strange, how have you installed JRuby? With RVM?

If you use rvm it's super easy to install and use jruby like every others ruby implementation.

```
rvm install jruby
rvm use jruby

jruby -v
gem install jruby-openssl
```

Comment: In any case, even without rvm the installation of jruby is easy, just put the jruby folder on a folder that is in $PATH...done.

Answer (score 8):

These are the steps showing how to pack `bio` and `jruby-openssl` into jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar becoming `biojruby.jar` (just for my purpose, I need `bioruby` for developing bioinformatics programs)

Here are the steps:

- Make sure you navigated into the directory containing jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar in terminal/console
- In terminal/console, type in:

  ```
  mkdir biojruby
  ```
- Just add any gems you want, for gems which written purely in ruby without any C extension will work in Jruby!

  ```
  java -jar jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar -S gem install -i ./biojruby bio
  java -jar jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar -S gem install -i ./biojruby jruby-openssl
  jar uf jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar -C biojruby .                                
  mv jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar biojruby.jar
  ```
- Now you can remove the folder "biojruby"
- Completed!

Now type in:

```
java -jar biojruby.jar -S gem list
```

and you will see (indicate success):

```
**** LOCAL GEMS ***
bio (1.4.2)
bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0146.1)
jruby-openssl (0.7.6.1)
rake (0.8.7)
sources (0.0.1)*
```

Now you can test with your ruby script by type in:

```
java -jar biojruby.jar #Your_Ruby_Script.rb#
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I was looking for my hbase jruby stuff.

Comment: In 2020, with jruby 9.2.10.0, this convenient process does not or no longer works. The local gem set is not updated as shown. If I understand where jRuby is looking for installed gems, it finds "local gems" in the users ~/.gems/jruby/<version> directory.

Given that, one would want the LOCAL GEMS set to be empty not populated for the Success outcome of the test.

Back in 2012 the script ran because the user's environment not the jar provided the needed gems. That is an undesirable configuration.

Comment: It would be nice if there would be a simpler way. I have written tons of ruby gems and only recently started with jruby, but I don't know how to install gems on jruby ...